# Yaml content parsing and making list from it - went wrong (python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, list, yaml

I try to make an input for plots. I have yaml files with some content (as year, resolution...) and I want to do a list, which would contain "years" from all of my desired yaml files and then I will use it later as input for plots.

**The list should look like that**: [2010, 2011, 2013,...]

**But my code gives me this list**:

[2014]

[2014, 2015]

[2014, 2015, 2015]

I assume that problem is somewhere in "for" cycles?

Here is the code:

```
import glob
import yaml

pdb_codes = ['3J7Z', '3J9Y', '3J9Z', '3JA1', '3JBU', '3JBV'] #just example of few, there are many more
years = []


for codes in pdb_codes:    
    # get directories
    directories = glob.glob("../../../../DATA/{}/" .format(codes))

    # sort directories because the glob method yields them unordered
    directories_sorted = sorted(directories)

    # browse directories
    for directory in directories_sorted:
        pdb_code = directory.split("/")[-2]   
        yaml_name = directory + pdb_code + ".yaml" 

        with open(yaml_name) as stream:
            yaml_content = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            year = yaml_content["Year"]
            years.append(year)

    print(years)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, my understanding is that there is only ONE yaml file in every directory, which you are reading and appending the year to the years list. As you are printing after each directory, only one year appending and the list is getting printed.
Try printing the list after the outer loop.

Sorry if I did not understand the question properly.